# Operator "?" and operator AND evaluation

Tags: php, evaluation, operator-precedence

This evaluates to TRUE.

```
$A = TRUE;
$B = FALSE;

$result = ($A) AND ($B) ? true : false;
```

Why is the evaluation giving true, and how exactly is the evaluation done step by step?

Thanks

Comment: See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php → `&&` instead of `AND` would have worked.

Comment: i searched previously, but in that page I can not find exactly in this case, why and how that AND is working with ?.
How the second "false" is being used in the evaluation? 
Thanks

Comment: Oh! AND have lower priority than "=".
Ok, then, the other "AND" how is used? it is discarted?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not related to the ternary. It's because `=` has a higher [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `and`. That means you're setting `$result = ($A)` and then everything after the `and` is irrelevant.

`($B) ? true : false` *does* evaluate to `false`, but because the assignment already happened in the first part of the expression, it's not assigned to anything. It's basically ignored.

For a more straightforward example, try

```
$result = true and false;
```

`$result` will be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

**My Initial thought was** It's returning `true` because of missing parenthesis. *Reason*:  *ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right*. See [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/E8q1q) it'll return `bool(false)` if you wrap it with parenthesis `()`

```
$A = TRUE;
$B = FALSE;

$result = (($A) AND ($B)) ? true : false;
var_dump($result);
```

**Edited:** **Why & how the second FALSE is being used?**

Because `and/or` have lower priority than `=`, but the `||` or `&&` have higher priority than `=`. For example.

```
<?php
$bool = true && false;
var_dump($bool); // false, that's expected

$bool = true and false;
var_dump($bool); // true, ouch!
?>
```

Hope it is clear now :). 
**source**: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php#117390

Comment: Thanks I know that wrapping works, but why how the second FALSE is being used? and how exactly gives the true, that is my interest in the quesiton.

Comment: @voskys. I've **Edited** my answer. Please have a look again :)